# Recuperar o context de uma Class (Model)

Tags: java, android, android-adapter

Tenho um model e estou querendo usar o "SharedPreferences" dentro dele.

Para instanciar o `SharedPreferences`, eu preciso do context(contexto), como eu faço para recuperar esse context?

```
public class PostagemCurtida {

    public Feed feed;
    public Usuario usuario;
    public int qtdCurtidas = 0;
    private Context context;

    public PostagemCurtida() {

    }

    final Preferencias preferencias = new Preferencias(context);

    public void salvar() {

        DatabaseReference firebaseRef = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebase();

        String usuarioCodificado = Base64Custom.codificarBase64(usuario.getEmail());

        HashMap<String, Object> dadosUsuario = new HashMap<>();
        dadosUsuario.put("nomeUsuario", usuario.getNome());
        dadosUsuario.put("caminhoFoto", usuario.getCaminhoFoto());



        DatabaseReference pCurtidasRef = firebaseRef.child("postagens-curtidas").child(preferencias.getFeedId()).child(usuarioCodificado);

        pCurtidasRef.setValue(dadosUsuario);

        atualizarQtde(1);

    }

    public void remover() {

        DatabaseReference firebaseRef = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebase();

        String usuarioCodificado = Base64Custom.codificarBase64(usuario.getEmail());

        DatabaseReference pCurtidasRef = firebaseRef.child("postagens-curtidas").child(preferencias.getFeedId()).child(usuarioCodificado);

        pCurtidasRef.removeValue();
        atualizarQtde(-1);

    }

    public void atualizarQtde(int valor) {

        DatabaseReference firebaseRef = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebase();

        String usuarioCodificado = Base64Custom.codificarBase64(usuario.getEmail());

        DatabaseReference pCurtidasRef = firebaseRef.child("postagens-curtidas").child(preferencias.getFeedId()).child("qtdCurtidas");

        setQtdCurtidas(getQtdCurtidas() + valor);

        pCurtidasRef.setValue(getQtdCurtidas());


    }

    public Feed getFeed() {
        return feed;
    }

    public void setFeed(Feed feed) {
        this.feed = feed;
    }

    public Usuario getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    public int getQtdCurtidas() {
        return qtdCurtidas;
    }

    public void setQtdCurtidas(int qtdCurtidas) {
        this.qtdCurtidas = qtdCurtidas;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private Context context;


public PostagemCurtida(Context context) {
     this.context = context;
}
```

E quando você chamar seu Model através de alguma classe, vc passa o contexto, por exemplo:

```
PostagemCurtida postagemCurtida = new PostagemCurtida(this);
```

Comment: Opa.. cometi um erro, ele n é um adapter e sim um model. Como faria para recuperar esse context em um model?

Comment: Você tem um constructor aonde vc passa os valores pro model?

Comment: Vou editar minha resposta mostrando o model completo.

Comment: Editei! o unico problema é o context q ainda n consegui recuperar!

Comment: Fiz uma edição na minha resposta, da uma olhada

Comment: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference.
       Deu esse erro, estou usando para chamar final PostagemCurtida curtida = new PostagemCurtida(context);

Comment: Você ta passando como *this* ou *context*?

Comment: Como onde estou chamando a PostagemCurtida é um Adpter(FeedAdapter ) eu estou usando o context, q fiz basicamente a mesma coisa para recuperar o context, que vc me falou para fazer nesse.